# Install an app by clicking on a link in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How i can install an app using the link or the path whose build is on a server or on a local mac machine.

Explanation:

I created an app with name "**app1**". There is another app with name "**app2**" which is already installed on simulator. I just want to install the app1 on to the simulator by clicking a link provided in app2.

Comment: [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=547557) might be helpful.

Comment: @Cfr not really. There the developer want to the users to use the simulator. Here OP doesn't want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a properly signed IPA and a `manifest.plist` file, then uploading them to your server should be sufficient - see [this complete tutorial](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html) on the topic.